# error when I create a new object of a php class

Tags: php, function, class

I coded this class with an static function into it.
why when I create a new object of this class I get an error?

```
<?php
class alluser
{
    private $var1;
    private $var2;

    public function __construct($string)
    {
        $this->var1 = $string;
        $this->var2 = self::user();
    }

    private static function user()
    {
        return $this->var1;

    }
}
?>
```

So I tried test this class:

```
$user=new alluser('admin');
```

I got this error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in G:\wampserver\www\ne43\test\cake\develop\classes\alluser.php on line 15
```

I think I couldn't use $this in static method but what is the best alernative method?

Comment: Just use a non-static method and write $this->user()

Comment: I know but I do not want use non-static method becuase of loading...

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, if you want to return an object property, you need an object so you cannot use a static method.

Comment: Could you explain what "because of loading" means please? I'd like to understand why you don't  think a non-static method is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this is **NOT** accessible in static content.

this works, but makes no sense for me:

```
<?php
class alluser {
    private static $var1;
    private $var2;

    public function __construct($string) {
        self::$var1 = $string;
        $this->var2 = self::user();
    }

    private static function user() {
        return self::$var1;
    }

    public function getVar1() {
        return self::$var1;
    }

}

$user=new alluser('admin');
echo $user->getVar1();
```

Comment: To clarify, the reason this works is that `$var1` will now have the same value for all instances of this class. There are genuine situations that call for this, but you need to be sure you have one of those situations and understand the consequences. In this particular example, it will hold whatever string was last used to construct an object of the class, which as michabbb says, doesn't make much sense.